# SQL Table for Timesheet creation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-design

I'm creating a timesheet using Infopath. The data will be stored in the database, so for that I have to create a table. This timesheet will be used for the whole year.

I need help in creating a SQL table. The table structure I want for this timesheet is:

```
Project_Category   Mon   Tue    Wed   Thu    Fri    Sat  Sun    Total
    Project 1   
    Project 2
    Project 3
    Project 4
    Project 5
    Other
    Total
```

The days should be with dates (Like, Monday 01/01/2013) or please suggest me if you have a better way to do this.

Comment: I think you should take a look here http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp

Comment: @JeremyWest is right. A basic understanding of SQL would help no end.

Answer (score 0):

I would not store this data in a single table.  Consider creating this using multiple tables instead of the single table.

For example, you could have a `Projects` table with `ProjectId` and `ProjectName`.  Then you could easily link your `ProjectId` field to a `ProjectSummary` table which stores `ProjectId`, `DateField` and `Total`.  I have no clue what your Total row is suppose to be, but if it's a calculation of a date range, use SQL to calculate those values and do not store that in the table.

Good luck -- there are lots of resources online to get started with SQL -- do a little searching.

Comment: Thanks for fast reply, the Total row is for total hours entered for the day and the other total is for total hours for the week. I'm new to SQL, can you please help with the script, I would really appreciate it

Comment: Here is some SQL Fiddle -- perhaps this will help -- good luck!  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/56ffe/2

Answer (score 0):

As sgeddes has suggested, multiple tables will probably be a much better way to approach this.

Personally I would avoid having more than 1 day per row and also to make it flexible allow more than one entry per day.

The structure I would create is as follows:

```
Entry_ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
Timesheet_ID INT,
Project_ID INT,
DateTimeFrom DATETIME,
DateTimeTo DATETIME
```

This then allows date based calculations to be much simpler.

eg. Number of hours on project X between 20th June and 25th June would be a query like:

```
SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTES,DateTimeFrom,DateTimeTo)/60) AS [HOURS]
FROM MyTable
WHERE DateTimeFrom >= '2012-06-25' AND DateTimeTo <= '2012-06-29'
```

Comment: bendataclear, one last question, Regarding the dates, I want all the dates to be entered instead of just start and end date. how can I do that